# Mock get request with Junit tests using data from h2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2

I know we can mock get request. Can we mock a get request and return data from h2 database?

My main application uses Oracle database. I was able to populate a h2 database and write a Junit test. But I just called a service. I want to make a get request and make it pull data from h2 database. How to write a Junit test for this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: can you show your test class code, you call follow this https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is `TestRestTemplate`.

### Testing with TestRestTemplate and @SpringBootTest

One of the easiest way to test, I think, what you are trying to do. It starts your entire Spring Boot application and give you the ability to interact with your REST Api through a `TestRestTemplate`.

You need to configure your projects with some maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, create a Test class. This class will starts your Spring Boot application and execute your tests.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    void testApplication() {
        int resourceId = 3;
        ResponseEntity<MyResponseObject> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/myEndPoint/{resourceId}", MyResponseObject, resourceId);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
        MyResponseObject  body = response.getBody();
        // then do what you want
    }
}
```

And basically, that is all. Here are the things to consider:

- `@SpringBootTest` will lookup for your annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` or `@SpringBootConfiguration`. Then, it will load everything you have (included services and h2 access).
- `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` will starts your server on any available PORT on your computer. You can then have many instances running at the same time.
- By adding the h2 to your class path on a testing environment, Spring will automatically creates the Datasource to talk to your h2 database. No need for extra configuration (usually I mean).
- `TestRestTemplate` is automatically provided by Spring Boot. As you noticed in my tests, I do not provide neither the host nor the port of my SpringBoot application under tests. Spring automatically connects to the good server... Magic.

If you want a tuto, follow this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate.
If you want Spring Boot Test docs, follow this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

When should you be using `TestRestTemplate`:

- When you tests across all the layers of your application
- When you want to have a test very close to what you will have in production

When should you not:

- When you application is too long to start. As it loads everything about your apps, if it usually takes 20 seconds to start, then your tests will make at least 20 seconds to execute. It's very long.
- When you have dependencies with system you do not control at all, you have to use `@MockBean` as well. It is not a silver bullet. It can work on your local machine but not on your CI server for instance. Be careful with that.

### Testing with MockMvc

With `MockMvc` you can also mock a test to your controller, you can mock a request. This is more restrictive than a global `@SpringBootTest`, as you don't fire up the entire applications, but just a small part, made to test the Web Controller Layer. Most of the times, you don't use it to test all the layers of your app, just the web part, by mocking the rest.

There is always a way to test through all the layers, but clearly, you need to add the class you want to fire yourself.

If you want to see how it looks like, go check this: https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring

If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruaro. I am going to try this and get back to you if I have any questions.

Comment: When I change values in my sql files, the tests dont reflect the changes right away. What do I need to do for that?

Comment: What do you mean by « don’t reflect the changes right away » ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Hi Ruaro The solution works great. I have this file data.sql that creates and populates the table in H2 for the tests. I have a create table statement and insert statements. If I change the values inserted and rerun the test. The changes dont get reflected if I select rerun test. I realized I have to close and reopen the junit window. Sometimes more than once. Thanks for your help